# why Partitions not using index key

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp` (
  `CallID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `InfoID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CallStartTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `PartitionID` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `CallStartTime`(`CallStartTime`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    PARTITION BY RANGE (`PartitionID`)(
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ( 50 ),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ( 100 ),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ( 150 ),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ( 200 ),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ( 250 ),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN ( 300 ),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN ( 350 ),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );
```

I am executing this query:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS 
 SELECT * 
   FROM tmp 
  WHERE (`PartitionID` BETWEEN dayofyear('2013-06-19 01:00:00') 
                           AND dayofyear('2013-08-13 12:10:06') )
    AND (CallStartTime  BETWEEN '2013-06-19 01:00:00' AND '2013-08-13 12:10:06')
```

RESULT:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  tmp           p3,p4     ALL CallStartTime               11  Using where
```

Comment: It looks like MySQL decided it would be better to not use the key. This usually happens when your filter retrieves 30-40% (or more) of all the rows in the table, in which case it is faster to do a table scan.

Comment: we can use here any force index for that

Comment: You can, but it's probably not necessary. Usually when MySQL does this it is the right thing to do. The same query with a smaller period of time should use the index.

Comment: how can i add force index

Comment: ``... FROM tmp FORCE KEY(`CallStartTime`)...``. Check [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) for more info.