# Why doesn't MySQL use my partitions as indices?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-partitioning

I created a table partitioned on a numeric ID:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
...
`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PARTITION BY HASH (`id`) PARTITIONS 100
```

I have no primary key, but a number of indices.  I don't have any data in my table where id is less than 0 or greater than 30 (at the moment, I expect this to grow).  Most of my queries first include the id to reduce the search space.

I figured a query to `select distinct(id) from mytable` would then just return the number of partitions that had data in it.  I was surprised that an explain on this instead does a full scan of the data:

```
explain partitions select distinct(id) from mytable;

|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22,p23,p24,p25,p26,p27,p28,p29,p30,p31,p32,p33,p34,p35,p36,p37,p38,p39,p40,p41,p42,p43,p44,p45,p46,p47,p48,p49,p50,p51,p52,p53,p54,p55,p56,p57,p58,p59,p60,p61,p62,p63,p64,p65,p66,p67,p68,p69,p70,p71,p72,p73,p74,p75,p76,p77,p78,p79,p80,p81,p82,p83,p84,p85,p86,p87,p88,p89,p90,p91,p92,p93,p94,p95,p96,p97,p98,p99 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 24667132 | Using temporary |

explain select distinct(id) from mytable;
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra           |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable              | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 24667132 | Using temporary |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+
```

I then read [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799365/mysql-partitioning-why-its-not-taking-appropriate-partition) answer which enlightened how MySQL's partition `hash()` function works.

My question is, how can I get MySQL to map each id in the table into its own partition such that selects with the id narrow the search to a single table (and a select distinct() just has to count the number of partitions and not scan them)?

I'm using `Server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (Ubuntu)`.

Comment: Whilst your current range of `id` values (integers 0 to 30) will each sit in their own partition, this is not guaranteed in the general case: there are 2^32 possible values, divided across 100 partitions - so plenty of opportunity for collisions.  Without inspecting the values that are actually stored, MySQL cannot know how many each partition holds.  Furthermore, `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM mytable` returns every (distinct) *value* of `id` within the partitioned `mytable`, not the *number* of such values: so merely "counting the number of partitions" could not suffice in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your conflating two different things. One is the fact that a `SELECT WHERE id = ?` should only search one partition. Something which you mentioned but didn't specify whether it currently works or not (given your table definition, I don't see why it shouldn't).

The second thing, having a `SELECT distinct(id)` to only touch the partitioning information, is very different from this. However, if I understand you correctly, you're assuming that one partition only has one kind of `id`. That is not how `HASH` partitioning works, though. It works similar to a traditional hash-table, by mapping a large key space to a small one, in your case, 100. So each partition will have many possible IDs. Since mysql will not keep track which of the possible IDs are really in one partition all it can do is to scan each partition, do the `DISTINCT`, and give back the result. That said, it could to do the `DISTINCT` operation on the individual partitions instead of the whole table and it could do this in parallel, however, the explain seems to imply that it will create one big temporary to do the `DISTINCT`, likely because this optimization hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Indeed you are right, when I set the `select where id=?` and explain that the number of rows considered is only two.  So that is as I had hoped. The `id` isn't a primary or unique key, there will be lots of rows with the same `id`.  However, I would like one id per partition.  Is there a way to instruct mysql to do this?  That all rows within a given partition will have the same id?

Comment: @Christopher: Yes, I think range partitioning should allow you to do this. Just specify 100 partitions with a range of 1 each.

Comment: Have a look at the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html) about range partitioning. I guess you can specify 100 partitions with a range of 1 each. There will be one overflow partition that could contain any ID, so your application logic will have to make sure that the maximum ID is 100 (better would be `CHECK` constraints, but mysql unfortunately doesn't support them).

Comment: There's no need to use range partitioning here.  `HASH` partitioning, as the OP had originally created, will achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @eggyal: Yeah, I just realized that, confused it with `KEY` partitioning, so part of what I wrote was wrong. Fixed now.